# Modifying a Multi-dimensional Array inside a function

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I have an assignment to find the transpose of a matrix (in c++) only using array indices.  My main calls the function indexTranspose, but I cannot figure out why when I print the array inside the function the output is correct, but when I print it out in the main the matrix is not updated.  The matrix is a text file full of 9 random ints.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//function declarations
void printMatrix(int m[][3]);
void indexTranspose(int n[3][3]);
//void pointerTranspose(int m[][3]);

//begin main
int main() {
    int m[3][3];
    ifstream values("matrix.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            values >> m[i][j];
    printMatrix(m);
    indexTranspose(m);
    printMatrix(m);
    /*pointerTranspose(m);
    printMatrix(m);
*/
} //end main

void printMatrix(int m[][3]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cout << "[ ";
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        cout << m[i][j] << " "; 
    cout << "]" << endl;
    }
    cout <<endl;
}

  void indexTranspose (int n[][3]) { 
    cout << "Transposing the matrix using indices..." <<endl;
    int temp[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            temp[j][i] = n[i][j];
        }
    n = temp;
    cout << "Printing n"<< endl;
    printMatrix(n);
    }
```

The output I get when I run this function is the original matrix, followed by the transpose (printed out inside the function), and then the original again.  I am not sure why the transpose function only updates the array locally instead of modifying the array in the main as well.

Comment: Arrays do not have proper value semantics. You can't  assign an array to another directly. Consider using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

Comment: `n = temp;` -- This does do what you think it does.  Use standard containers, where `=` works as intended.

Comment: Assigning to a parameter has no effect outside the function.

Comment: Simply change to `typedef std::array<std::array<int, 3>> Matrix`, declare your 2d matrix like this, pass `Matrix` by reference, and then things will magically work.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't try to re-assign `n` inside the `indexTranspose` function. Instead, swap individual values within the array.
Swap `i, j` with `j, i` and make sure that you don't separately swap `j, i` with `i, j` later.

```
void indexTranspose (int n[][3])
{ 
    std::cout << "Transposing the matrix using indices..." << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        // the j < i ensures, that i, j are not swapped twice and i, i is never swapped because its the same index anyway
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            std::swap(n[i][j], n[j][i]);
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Printing n"<< std::endl;
    printMatrix(n);
}
```

To use `std::swap`, add an include for `<algorithm>` (C++98) or `<utility>` (C++11 and above).